# Join multiple branches to a main path without connecting branches

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am pretty new in the Illustration world and as my first design I need a branching path.

I started joining my first arrow to the main path... however, when I add the second arrow to the main path, it also connects the second arrow to the first arrow. I only want the second arrow to be connected to the main path. How can I solve this? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

### You can't.

Illustrator paths are built on a point-by-point logic and this is way you can only connect the first arrow. The other arrows cannot be 'glued' on to the same path, they can touch the main path, but they need to exist as separate objects. You can start 2 paths from the same point, but they will not be part of a single object.

To illustrate this, when you see something like the image below, that can never be a single path, but in fact a group of separate paths.

[image]

Comment: "The other arrows cannot be 'glued' on to the same path, they can touch the main path, but they need to exist as separate objects." 
But, then how can I make them not overlapping but like branches?

Comment: Not sure what this means, probably try to remove the transparency. If all the lines are black, it will look like they're the same shape, even though that not technically what they are. The image you posted the lines are transparent, you can 'see through' then so obviously they look separated.

Comment: actually, I want to be able to keep their transparency but at the same time do not want to have those intersecting parts to be visible. Is there such a way while keeping transparency?

Comment: @Eylul Draw it all **without** transparency. Group them. Then adjust transparency on the **Group** (Appearance Panel) not the individual objects.

Comment: What @Scott is saying. Grouping is kind of a workaround to your problem. Multiple paths can be grouped and then different properties can be applied to a group of paths.